# MacOS Sierra: ERROR: volume / is mounted with write access. Re-run with (-l) to freeze volume

Tags: macos, mount, error

MacBook Pro 17'' (Early 2011) with Sierra 10.12.6 e new SSD.

I found this error in the Filesystem repair log, after installation of Sierra on my new SSD:

```
/dev/rdisk1: ERROR: volume / is mounted with write access. Re-run with (-l) to freeze volume.
```

Filesystem repair log:

```
/dev/rdisk0s3: fsck_hfs started at Sun Oct 28 19:51:22 2018
/dev/rdisk0s3: /dev/rdisk0s3: ** /dev/rdisk0s3 (NO WRITE)
/dev/rdisk0s3:    Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-305.10.1).
QUICKCHECK ONLY; FILESYSTEM CLEAN
/dev/rdisk0s3: fsck_hfs completed at Sun Oct 28 19:51:22 2018


/dev/rdisk1: fsck_hfs started at Sun Oct 28 19:51:25 2018
/dev/rdisk1: /dev/rdisk1: ERROR: volume / is mounted with write access. Re-run with (-l) to freeze volume.
/dev/rdisk1: fsck_hfs completed at Sun Oct 28 19:51:25 2018
```

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: Have you found the same error? Did you manage to solve it? Or have you got some ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The system starts anyway but hadn't figured out how to get rid of the error.

Comment: Many people have this kind of error. I think it's a normal error: a non-error. Anyway, if you solve it, can you tell me? Thanks.